# S Memo missing after OS upgrade

Tags: updates

I have upgraded Galaxy Note to Jelly Bean (v4.1.2). The problem is it does not have the S Memo application installed. Can I get that application and install it to my Galaxy Note? If not, then how do I get it back to its original state where I can use S Memo?

Comment: Was this a regular update or did you root and apply a custom ROM? (The latter is implied by your original tags, but you make no mention of how you got the update in your question.)

Comment: Well sir, infact i have purchased the phone with the said version of jelly beans. I have no idea of how this phone was updated. It is not even connecting to Kies.

Comment: So then you didn't upgrade the phone. Did you buy it new or from a third-party?

Comment: from a third party. a used phone. actually i am looking for the s note software.

Comment: This is important information that you should include in your question.

Comment: hmm. can you help?

Comment: Just click the [edit] link under your post and edit your question.